# SQL chacter delete

Tags: mysql, sql, database, validation

Im new in SQL and I have some troubles figuring out how correctly this should be done.

I need to make an sql validation.
When users enter some characters in **`ID=1`** I need to delete those characters from **`ID=2`**

For example:
There are two fields and when user enters `ABC` in `ID=1` field I need the second field `ID=2` to be `123` not `ABC123`

[ID1 & ID2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpZOl.png)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text! (Not images, or links to images.)

Comment: _Column_, not field.

Comment: This sounds like a task better suited to your application than the database?

Comment: I need to write a query for that application

Comment: @ArtyomGrindenka are you saying that the data already exists in those columns in your database and want to UPDATE the value in column ID=2?

Comment: @PaulCampbell in a way. Every single code belongs to different companies and I already have those codes in my DB. But when our accountants fills the information they usually just copy/paste the entire information.

Comment: What I want to do is to create a query that will check ID1 characters with ID2 characters and will delete the same characters if they are in ID2

Comment: See answer below for suggested solution. Also, you could save yourself a world of pain by not using column names like ID=1 and ID=2, they aren't  descriptive and using '=' just means you'll have to quote all the column names.

Answer (score 0):

After you have backed up your data ...

try something like this

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET `ID=2` = SUBSTRING(`ID=2`,LENGTH(`ID=1`)+1) 
WHERE LOCATE(`ID=1`,`ID=2`) = 1;
```